# Android XML UI inheritance

Tags: android, xml, inheritance

How to extend an Activity that has some UI component defined in XML, and display them in it's sub-class  which may have some other components of it's own?

Comment: what do you exactly mean?

Comment: I'm talking about reusing xml layout. If I have to display a Button in every activity of my App,I won't have to write them in every xml.

Comment: what about overriding setContentView?

Comment: That's the only way I found for the moment.But I haven't figured out how to do it :p

Comment: you can also use getLayoutInflater().setFactory(this)

Comment: Thanks @pskink,I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse and inflate the same xml layout in every activity you use if you want.
If you just need to use one component like a button then you could define it in a separate xml document and then use the  tag to bring it in to another layout.  You wouldn't need to use any java inheritance for this unless you wanted to add buttons programmatically.

Here is some more info the  for reusing xml.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: Yeah, it just one component that I want to use in every activity, but I don't wanna include it in every xml too.I want to simply inherit the base view that holding this component,and no extra code or xml. Perhaps the only way to do this is to override setContentView, but I haven't figured out how.

Comment: I came across this tutorial/blog of a developer who insists on coding all of his UI and display instead of using xml editors and layouts.  It seems like a lot more work, but if you could design your perfect componant and set it up in a separate java file, you could access its design and add it to anything.  

http://www.pocketmagic.net/2011/03/android-gui-with-headerscrollable-contentfooter/#.U_D0xnWSzVN